# nano M-A hotkey

Tags: nano

When using nano in the terminal, to do the "write file append" command, it lists the keystroke "M-A".

I am completely confused what this key command actually means. I read somewhere that it means Alt-A, which didn't work.

What am I supposed to use?

EDIT: I think the problem is because when I hit Alt-A, it opens my Xubuntu terminal windows Menu > Tabs menu item.

So by default the supplied xubuntu / xfce terminal has hotkeys that step on nano's hotkeys? Is this correct or have I modified them and forgot?

Comment: "didn't work" how exactly? Alt-A should be the right interpretation - the slightly confusing thing is that the keymapping only applies in the "write screen" (i.e. after you've hit Ctrl-O). In regular edit mode, M-A (Alt-A) sets a mark in the text.

Comment: Try `esc` then `A` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M-A means <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. But that does not directly appends the contents to the file selected.

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> toggles the mode of modification of file between "write to file" and "append to file" as shown in the following images.

> [image: File name to write to]

> [image: File name to append to]

After you toggle to the desired command, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
This will append the contents to the file.

Comment: Why use "M" in the hints? Wouldn't be more logical to use "A"?

Answer (score 2):

A test example using the `append` write file output option.
Starting conditions:

```
doug@s15:~$ cat cccc
this is file cccc.
doug@s15:~$ cat bbbb
this is file bbbb.
```

Now, `nano cccc`, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> but change this:

```
File Name to Append to: cccc
```

To this:

```
File Name to Append to: bbbb
```

And then <kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
See this:

```
doug@s15:~$ cat bbbb
this is file bbbb.
this is file cccc.
```

Note: There are other key combinations to achieve the same end result. See the help file within `nano`, a segment extracted below:

```
 The notation for shortcuts is as follows: Control-key sequences are
 notated with a caret (^) symbol and can be entered either by using the
 Control (Ctrl) key or pressing the Escape (Esc) key twice.  Escape-key
 sequences are notated with the Meta (M-) symbol and can be entered using
 either the Esc, Alt, or Meta key depending on your keyboard setup.
```